Module error = from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
I am creating a Telegram Python-based bot, but I encountered an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kamal Wixpa\Desktop\New folder\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
  File "C:\Users\Kamal Wixpa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from . import filters
  File "C:\Users\Kamal Wixpa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telegram\ext\filters.py", line 122, in <module>
    from telegram import Chat as TGChat
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram' (C:\Users\Kamal Wixpa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)

Environment:
Python Version: 3.12.3
python-telegram-bot Version: 21.2 : pip install python-telegram-bot

Code:
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
from telegram import Update
import random

BOT_TOKEN = "sdfdsf"

def generate_luhn_digit(num):
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
    checksum = 0
    reverse_digits = digits[::-1]

    for i, digit in enumerate(reverse_digits):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            double = digit * 2
            checksum += double - 9 if double > 9 else double
        else:
            checksum += digit

    return str((10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10)

def handle_cc_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    try:
        query = update.message.text.split(" ")[1]

        if not query[:-1].isdigit() or not query[-1].isdigit():
            update.message.reply_text("Invalid input. Please provide a numeric credit card base.")
            return

        luhn_num = generate_luhn_digit(query[:-1])

        if "|" in query:
            expiry_data = query.split("|")[1].split()
            if len(expiry_data) == 2:
                expiry_month, expiry_year = expiry_data
            else:
                expiry_month = expiry_data[0]
                expiry_year = str(random.randint(20, 30)) + str(random.randint(0, 9))
        else:
            expiry_month = str(random.randint(1, 12)).zfill(2)
            expiry_year = str(random.randint(20, 30)) + str(random.randint(0, 9))

        cvv = str(random.randint(100, 999))

        full_cc = f"{query[:-1]}{luhn_num}|{expiry_month}|{expiry_year}|{cvv}"
        update.message.reply_text(f"Generated Credit Card Number: {full_cc}")

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text("Please provide a valid input format.")

def handle_unknown_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Unknown command")


updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("cc", handle_cc_command))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.command, handle_unknown_message))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()


error shows full path to files with telegram source code - maybe you should check what is in these files. maybe it needs to delete all manually and install it again.

I tested all your imports with python-telegram-bot 21.2 on python 3.12.3 but on Linux and it works for me. Maybe it is problem only with WIndows, or it is problem only with your system.

Does this answer your question? Unable to run Python Telegram Bot Package - Error
